# SuSE 11: "top" CPU percentages don't add up

Tags: top, sles

Running "top -b" on my SLES 11sp2 system produces the output below. The Cpu(s) line reports 33.7% CPU usage in user space, but if you add up the %CPU column in the process listing you only get 4.9% usage.

I've read answers to similar questions that say "top hides some processes, get htop to see them all".  Installing htop is not an option in this customer environment, so I'm just looking to understand what it is that top might hide, why, and how to see all processes' CPU utilization using the default Linux toolset.

Thanks.

```
top - 09:43:53 up 22:23,  5 users,  load average: 0.33, 0.08, 0.02
Tasks: 139 total,   6 running, 133 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 33.7%us,  8.6%sy,  0.0%ni, 57.1%id,  0.3%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.3%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   2007648k total,   783040k used,  1224608k free,   158104k buffers
Swap:  2096440k total,        0k used,  2096440k free,   379820k cached
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
 2078 root      15   0  7760 4948 2508 S  2.0  0.2   0:00.06 python
 1936 root      15   0  7528 4864 2436 S  0.7  0.2   0:00.08 python
 2182 root      16   0  5120 2132 1732 S  0.7  0.1   0:00.02 ssh
 2183 root      17   0  8592 2548 2056 S  0.3  0.1   0:00.01 sshd
 2185 root      21   0  3704 1408 1172 R  0.3  0.1   0:00.01 bash
 2201 root      16   0  5124 1968 1588 S  0.3  0.1   0:00.01 ssh
 3574 root      34  19     0    0    0 R  0.3  0.0   0:01.34 kipmi0
 3693 root      15   0  104m 1052  792 S  0.3  0.1   0:05.77 nscd
    1 root      16   0   732  280  240 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.70 init
    2 root      34  19     0    0    0 R  0.0  0.0   0:00.02 ksoftirqd/0
    3 root      10  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.02 events/0
    4 root      10  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 khelper
    5 root      10  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthread
    8 root      10  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.01 kblockd/0
    9 root      20  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kacpid
   10 root      20  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kacpi_notify
  160 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 pdflush
  161 root      15   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.07 pdflush
  162 root      15   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.74 kswapd0
  163 root      18  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 aio/0
  374 root      11  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 cqueue/0
  375 root      10  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kseriod
  417 root      11  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kpsmoused
  751 root      10  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:03.11 ata/0
  752 root      11  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ata_aux
  765 root      10  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 scsi_eh_0
  766 root      10  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:08.17 scsi_eh_1
  771 root      10  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 scsi_eh_2
  772 root      10  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 scsi_eh_3
  854 root      15   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.55 kjournald
  915 root      12  -4  2424  600  352 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.21 udevd
 1516 root      10  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 khubd
 1531 root      16   0  2240 1040  764 R  0.0  0.1   0:00.04 top
 1533 root      15   0  2056  584  516 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 mgetty
 1928 root      15   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kjournald
 1967 root      11  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kauditd
 2202 root      17   0  6436 1956 1596 R  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 sshd
 2203 sshd      17   0  6436 1204  836 R  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 sshd
 2298 root      15   0  2088  764  468 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.79 syslog-ng
 2303 root      15   0  1704  520  320 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.14 klogd
 2312 100       16   0  3500  972  736 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.09 dbus-daemon
 2314 root      16   0  1572  500  416 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 acpid
 2357 root      15   0  1864  664  536 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 resmgrd
 2408 root      16   0  4704 3256 1444 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.58 hald
 2649 root      20   0  1872  620  536 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 hald-addon-acpi
 2810 root      16   0  1864  592  508 S  0.0  0.0   0:12.63 hald-addon-stor
 3262 root      10  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 bond0
 3383 root      10  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 bond1
 3504 nobody    16   0  1608  424  328 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 portmap
 3521 daemon    16   0  3288  896  636 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 slpd
 3529 root      11  -5     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rpciod/0
 3530 root      15   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 lockd
 3630 admin     18   0  2548 1104  852 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 su
 3631 root      15   0  1628  412  348 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 startpar
 3645 ntp       16   0  3968 1368 1064 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.02 ntpd
 3661 admin     17   0  3908 1604 1292 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.02 bash
 3674 root      16   0  1940  736  596 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 cron
 3783 root      16   0  4336 1736 1388 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.01 powersaved
 3820 root      15   0  5096 1136  796 S  0.0  0.1   0:02.49 sshd
 3862 admin     16   0 15268 9.9m 1800 S  0.0  0.5   0:00.71 Xvnc
 3865 root      16   0  4396 1056  804 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.01 ha_logd
 3867 root      16   0  4396  932  680 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ha_logd
 3892 root      16   0  6708 2148 1148 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.03 snmptrapd
 3928 admin     19   0  3704 1252 1044 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 xstartup
 3933 admin     16   0  3712 1408 1152 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.02 kde
 3935 root      -2   0 12320  12m 4420 S  0.0  0.6   0:01.30 heartbeat
 3958 root      16   0 20204 1860 1228 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.10 acpsnmpd
 3961 nobody    -2   0  5724 5724 4420 S  0.0  0.3   0:00.00 heartbeat
 3962 nobody    -2   0  5720 5720 4420 S  0.0  0.3   0:00.01 heartbeat
 3963 nobody    -2   0  5720 5720 4420 S  0.0  0.3   0:00.00 heartbeat
 3964 nobody    -2   0  5720 5720 4420 S  0.0  0.3   0:00.00 heartbeat
 3965 nobody    -2   0  5720 5720 4420 S  0.0  0.3   0:01.53 heartbeat
 4008 admin     16   0 24328 7056 5864 S  0.0  0.4   0:00.04 kdeinit
 4041 admin     15   0 23512 2632 1512 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.02 dcopserver
 4154 admin     16   0 24048 7908 6652 S  0.0  0.4   0:00.02 klauncher
 4172 admin     16   0 31584  14m  11m S  0.0  0.7   0:00.23 kded
 4174 root      18   0  2008  668  588 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.01 mingetty
 4175 root      18   0  2008  644  568 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 mingetty
 4176 root      18   0  2012  648  568 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 mingetty
 4177 root      18   0  2008  644  568 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 mingetty
 4178 root      18   0  2012  648  568 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 mingetty
 4179 root      18   0  2008  644  568 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 mingetty
 4180 root      15   0 14444 4592 1952 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.13 python
 4181 root      15   0  5556 3804 1896 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.61 python
 4183 root      16   0  5840 4068 1908 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.07 python
 4185 root      16   0  1568  492  424 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 agetty
 4217 admin     25   0  3712 1364 1128 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 startx
 4241 admin     17   0  2564  652  552 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 xinit
 4242 root      16   0 30652 8696 5584 S  0.0  0.4   0:01.66 X
 4270 admin     16   0  1552  356  288 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kwrapper
 4273 admin     16   0 26904  10m 8416 S  0.0  0.5   0:00.06 ksmserver
 4283 admin     16   0 29152  12m  10m S  0.0  0.6   0:00.17 kwin
 4328 admin     16   0  6924 4816 4168 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.03 vncviewer
 4354 admin     16   0 29412  14m  12m S  0.0  0.7   0:00.23 kdesktop
 4368 root      16   0  1684  556  420 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 inotifywait
 4369 admin     15   0 30704  14m  11m S  0.0  0.7   0:00.20 kicker
 4430 admin     16   0 24824 6560 5316 S  0.0  0.3   0:00.00 kio_file
 4440 admin     16   0 27012   9m 8368 S  0.0  0.5   0:00.05 kaccess
 4444 admin     16   0 27176  10m 8636 S  0.0  0.5   0:00.06 knotify
 4453 admin     16   0 28040  11m 9420 S  0.0  0.6   0:00.09 klipper
 5181 root      16   0 47340 5876 3500 S  0.0  0.3   0:00.07 httpd2-prefork
 5184 wwwrun    16   0 47832 4940 2040 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.08 httpd2-prefork
 5185 wwwrun    15   0 47592 4652 1984 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.12 httpd2-prefork
 5186 wwwrun    16   0 47892 4844 1988 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.16 httpd2-prefork
 5187 wwwrun    15   0 47592 4640 1984 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.10 httpd2-prefork
 5188 wwwrun    16   0 47596 4660 1988 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.08 httpd2-prefork
 5513 root      24   0  3424  940  720 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 vsftpd
 9662 admin     16   0 27100  12m  10m S  0.0  0.6   0:00.13 kdesktop_lock
 9663 admin     37  19 22020  10m 8864 S  0.0  0.5   0:00.10 kblankscrn.kss
16902 wwwrun    15   0 47740 4784 1984 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.10 httpd2-prefork
16912 nobody    20   0  3660  492  312 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 shellinaboxd
16913 nobody    20   0  3660  440  256 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 shellinaboxd
16918 wwwrun    16   0 47728 4836 2040 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.07 httpd2-prefork
17192 wwwrun    15   0 47592 4516 1988 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.01 httpd2-prefork
22897 root      30  15 10384 4788 2928 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.10 snmpd
23153 postgres  16   0 46384 5704 5376 S  0.0  0.3   0:00.34 postmaster
23157 postgres  15   0 46384 2196 1832 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 postmaster
23158 postgres  15   0 46384  904  568 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 postmaster
23159 postgres  16   0 46912 1900 1124 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 postmaster
23160 postgres  16   0  8120  996  552 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 postmaster
23348 root      15   0  8424 2464 1932 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.75 sshd
23529 root      16   0  5112 1564 1024 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.06 sftp-server
23873 wwwrun    16   0 47728 4756 1984 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.04 httpd2-prefork
23895 root      16   0  8644 2436 1948 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.74 sshd
23980 root      16   0  4188 1924 1412 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.08 bash
24531 root      16   0  8480 2428 1952 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.01 sshd
24536 root      15   0  4192 1924 1412 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.04 bash
24564 root      16   0  5124 2140 1728 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.01 ssh
27855 root      16   0  8480 2424 1948 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.02 sshd
27858 root      15   0  4188 1920 1408 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.05 bash
27886 man       17   0  2500 1344  796 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.12 man
27887 man       15   0  2808 1196  988 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 sh
27891 man       16   0  2224  912  728 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.01 less
31829 root      16   0  8656 2660 2056 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.14 sshd
31915 root      16   0  4188 1920 1408 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.06 bash
```